# Spring Boot and AWS RDS Read Replica

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-rds, read-replication

Here I am trying to achieve the below in AWS RDS. I have a MySQL database instance running. I am thinking of creating a read replica so that I will have some extra load sharing capabilities.

I have a Spring Boot application running on EC2. Currently the way I connect to the database is by adding the below properties in the application.yml:

```
datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://DB_HOSTNAME:3306/DB_DATABASE?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: DB_USERNAME
    password: DB_PASSWORD
```

My question is:

- If I create a read replica, do I need to write some special code to connect to it?
- Do I need multiple connection pools one for each instance of the database?
- How is this scalable from code perspective, if I have 5 read replicas, how do I manage this in code?
- How do I direct my database calls to different replicas? What is the basis of this decision?

If there is any link/video/documentation you can point me to. Spring boot is not a necessity, I need to understand what is a good way to utilize my read replicas from a Java application.

Thanks

Comment: "How do I direct my database calls to different replicas? What is the basis of this decision?"

If you configure Spring cloud any data access method @Transaction(readOnly=true) will be directed to the read replicas. 

The basis is : Ifyou are reading only read which you can live will bit state data (eg: not used for read&update kind of senarios, you can live with it.

Answer (score 3):

If we use `spring-cloud-aws-jdbc`
Then

**Point 1**
How to connect to Main and read replica instances

```
cloud.aws.rds.<DB-Instance-ID>.username=admin1
cloud.aws.rds.<DB-Instance-ID>.password=Admin123
cloud.aws.rds.<DB-Instance-ID>.databaseName=employee
cloud.aws.rds.employee-db.readReplicaSupport=true
```

**Point 2**

No Need to define a separate connection pool

**Point 3**

Spring Cloud AWS will search for any read-replica that is created for the master database and route the read-only transactions to **one of the read-replicas** that are available.

**Point 4**

You can redirect read transactions by

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
```

You can find a working example and details explanation [here](https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2022/04/24/Spring-Boot-AWS-RDS-Read-Replica-Part-2/)

Comment: does spring always pick a read replica that is in the same availability zone as the spring boot application? I'm asking because you mention spring could use _any_ of the available replicas. I have a read replica in us-east-a1 and in eu-central-a1, will the spring boot application pick the read replica in  eu-central-a1 when the ec2 server that has the spring application is also in that AZ zone? Or is there a chance that it might pick the one in us-east-a1 as well?

Comment: I have followed same link @Niraj https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2022/04/24/Spring-Boot-AWS-RDS-Read-Replica-Part-2/ but I am getting sometime profile not set errors, and token url connection issue, Reported issue under the same above your git link. https://github.com/nirajsonawane/spring-boot-aws-postgresql-read-replica/issues/2